# How to validate whether a c++ program is well documented using Doxygen format or not?

Tags: c++, doxygen, code-documentation

Is there a way for Doxygen to report whether source code is documented or not? Is there any way to identify the set of files which are not well documented in a set of C++ source files?

- Coding Language: C++
- Documentation Tool : Doxygen (This can be changed with some other open tool if it has an option for validation)

```cpp
/// \brief  Main function
/// \param  argc An integer argument count of the command line arguments
/// \param  argv An argument vector of the command line arguments
/// \return an integer 0 upon exit success
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Comments I would like to be documented in as well
    return 0;
}
```

The command which I have used is as follows

```
$> doxygen Doxyfile && echo "success" || echo "failed"
```

Comment: Requests for tools are off topic here and should be made  the sister site software recommendations. In doxygen there is no such facility except for checking the warnings that doxygen gives

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it belongs to Software recommendations.

Comment: Not necessarily a software recommendation, one can do it with doxygen. I had an answer almost ready, but the question was closed before I could post it.

Comment: @Striezel is your answer different from my comment regarding the warnings?

Comment: @albert: Yes, doxygen can give a clean non-zero exit code in that case, if configured to do that. That should allow detection of undocumented code in CI pipelines or similar places.

Comment: So not really different just using the setting `WARN_AS_ERROR=YES` and is still a bit away from what OP wants, he wants a set of files that are not well documented and not the first error and stop (my interpretation), but still it will probably good to know for him.

Comment: Depends on how one interprets the question, but basically `WARN_AS_ERROR=FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` and some other settings (`EXTRACT_ALL = NO`, `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = YES`, `WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR = YES`, `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = YES`) should do the trick. `WARN_AS_ERROR=FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` is better than just `WARN_AS_ERROR=YES` in that case, because it will not stop after the first warning / undocumented code, but go on to show all further warnings and then finish with a non-zero exit code, if there is undocumented stuff. This should basically show all files with undocumented code as warnings.

Comment: @Striezel Thank you Striezel for your solution. The tsolution is almost matching with my expectation. It is working as expected when there is mis matching arguments or formats

Comment: @Striezel Oops I forgot on the possibility I added regarding`WARN_AS_ERROR=FAIL_ON_WARNINGS`

Comment: @Striezel I just reopened the question.

Comment: @albert: Thanks. :)

Comment: @ThomasEaso I've constrained the question to make it clearly about Doxygen in particular. This is to avoid people (like myself) from assuming it's a software recommendation question.

Comment: Thank you @KenWayneVanderLinde for the modification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doxygen already provides some useful [configuration options](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html):

> **WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED**
>
> If the `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED` tag is set to `YES` then doxygen will generate warnings for undocumented members. If `EXTRACT_ALL` is set to `YES` then this flag will automatically be disabled.

> **WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR**
>
> If the `WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR` tag is set to `YES`, doxygen will generate warnings for potential errors in the documentation, such as not documenting some parameters in a documented function, or documenting parameters that don't exist or using markup commands wrongly.

> **WARN_NO_PARAMDOC**
>
> This `WARN_NO_PARAMDOC` option can be enabled to get warnings for functions that are documented, but have no documentation for their parameters or return value. If set to `NO`, doxygen will only warn about wrong or incomplete parameter documentation, but not about the absence of documentation. If `EXTRACT_ALL` is set to `YES` then this flag will automatically be disabled.

And finally:

> **WARN_AS_ERROR**
>
> If the `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to `YES` then doxygen will immediately stop when a warning is encountered. If the `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS` then doxygen will continue running as if `WARN_AS_ERROR` tag is set to `NO`, but at the end of the doxygen process doxygen will return with a non-zero status.
>
> Possible values are: `NO`, `YES` and `FAIL_ON_WARNINGS`.

So let's put all this together. The Doxyfile needs to contain the following settings:

```
# EXTRACT_ALL = NO is needed, or otherwise some of the 
#               other flags are disabled automatically.
EXTRACT_ALL = NO
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC = YES
# WARN_AS_ERROR could also be NO, but then
# it stops after the first documentation error.
WARN_AS_ERROR = YES
```

That way doxygen will show all undocumented code and it will exit with a non-zero, if there is undocumented code.

Comment: This solution is working. Anyone who is referring to the same problem can be resolved with the above steps. Thank you Striezel